# I am getting an error message while installing the rle-python-interface package

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
Collecting rle-python-interface (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
  Using cached rle_python_interface-1.1.5.tar.gz (3.1 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: neat-python==0.92 in c:\users\linden-pc\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 3)) (0.92)
Building wheels for collected packages: rle-python-interface
  Building wheel for rle-python-interface (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 4294967295
  ╰─> [27 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      creating C:\Users\Linden-PC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-sk644hx1\rle-python-interface_df4e0b5e650d4519ab303485857f83d2\build
      cmake .. -DBUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF -DBUILD_PYTHON=ON
      -- Building for: NMake Makefiles
      CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:1 (cmake_minimum_required):
        Compatibility with CMake < 3.5 will be removed from a future version of
        CMake.

        Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
        CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.


      CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (project):
        Running

         'nmake' '-?'

        failed with:

         The system cannot find the file specified


      CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
      CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
      -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
      Error while running cmake
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for rle-python-interface
  Running setup.py clean for rle-python-interface
Failed to build rle-python-interface
ERROR: Could not build wheels for rle-python-interface, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Collecting rle-python-interface (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
  Using cached rle_python_interface-1.1.5.tar.gz (3.1 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: neat-python==0.92 in c:\users\linden-pc\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 3)) (0.92)
Building wheels for collected packages: rle-python-interface
  Building wheel for rle-python-interface (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 4294967295
  ╰─> [27 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      creating C:\Users\Linden-PC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-sk644hx1\rle-python-interface_df4e0b5e650d4519ab303485857f83d2\build
      cmake .. -DBUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF -DBUILD_PYTHON=ON
      -- Building for: NMake Makefiles
      CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:1 (cmake_minimum_required):
        Compatibility with CMake < 3.5 will be removed from a future version of
        CMake.

        Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
        CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.


      CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (project):
        Running

         'nmake' '-?'

        failed with:

         The system cannot find the file specified


      CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
      CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
      -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
      Error while running cmake
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for rle-python-interface
  Running setup.py clean for rle-python-interface
Failed to build rle-python-interface
ERROR: Could not build wheels for rle-python-interface, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I am getting this error message. I have tried installing wheel seperately and i have tried the RLE package as well. I have also tried installing cmake and many more packages but I can't seem to install it.

The program i am installing this for is from this github: https://github.com/nadavbh12/Retro-Learning-Environment